# Transform a dataframe in R by turning column values into row values

Tags: r

Here's a simple example.

```
         A        B       C
1      100       NA       NA
2       NA      200       NA
3       NA       NA      300
```

What I want:

```
1        A      100       
2        B      200       
3        C      300
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are a lot of posts on SO on reshaping wide data to long data, many using `tidyr`. You could then filter to remove NAs. Which posts have you looked at, and what didn't work already?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the data in long format and drop the `NA` values.

Using `tidyr::pivot_longer` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

res <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything(), values_drop_na = TRUE)
res

#  name  value
#  <chr> <int>
#1 A       100
#2 B       200
#3 C       300
```

Using `data.table` -

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), measure.vars = names(df), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stack` from `base R`

```
na.omit(stack(df1)[2:1])
```

-ouptut

```
 ind values
1   A    100
5   B    200
9   C    300
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(100L, NA, NA), B = c(NA, 200L, NA), C = c(NA, 
NA, 300L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"
))
```